# How to call an external function inside fprintf

Tags: matlab, function, printf, octave

1. This is the external function : which is used to change the coordinates of the chess board to alphanumeric data instead of pure numbers.

   ```
   function [] = convertIntegerToCoordinates (i)
   First=floor(i/10);

   if      First ==1 fprintf('A') 
   elseif First ==5 fprintf('E')
   elseif First ==6 fprintf('F')
   elseif First ==7 fprintf('G')
   elseif First ==8 fprintf('H')
   end 
   Second=i-(10*First);
   if Second ==1 fprintf('1')
   elseif Second ==2 fprintf('2')
   elseif Second ==3 fprintf('3')
   elseif Second ==4 fprintf('4')
   elseif Second ==5 fprintf('5')
   elseif Second ==6 fprintf('6')
   elseif Second ==7 fprintf('7')
   elseif Second ==8 fprintf('8')

   end 

   endfunction
   ```

2.This is the main function : the function which is used to detect if a white king is on threat by any of the four of Rook, Bishop, Queen,and Knight.

```
    function [] = ChessThreatCheck (n,b,c)

    B = 'B';
    R = 'R';
    Q = 'Q';
    K = 'K'; 


    n= input("Please enter the coordinates of white king: ");
    whiteFirst=floor(n/10);
    whiteSecond=n-(10*whiteFirst);

    if (whiteFirst>8 || whiteFirst<1) && (whiteSecond>8 || whiteSecond<1)
    fprintf ('The x and y coordinates of the white king should be between 1 and 8\n');
    return;
    end 
    if whiteFirst>8 || whiteFirst<1
    fprintf('The x coordinate of white king should be between 1 and 8\n');
    elseif whiteSecond>8 || whiteSecond<1 
    fprintf('The y coordinate of white king should be between 1 and 8\n');
    return;
    end 


    b = input("Please enter the type of black chessman: ");
    if b != B && b!= R && b!= Q && b!= K 
    fprintf('The type of the black chessman can be (B)ishop, (R)ook, (Q)ueen or (K)night\n');
    return;
    end 


    c = input("Please enter the coordinates of black chessman: ");
    blackFirst = floor(c/10);
    blackSecond = c-(10*blackFirst);

    if (blackFirst<1 || blackFirst>8) && (blackSecond<1 || blackSecond>8)
    fprintf('The x and y coordinates of the black chessman should be between 1 and 8\n')
    return;
    end
    if blackFirst<1 || blackFirst>8 
    fprintf('The x coordinate of the black chessman should be between 1 and 8\n');
    elseif blackSecond<1 || blackSecond>8
    fprintf('The y coordinate of the black chessman should be between 1 and 8\n');
    return; 
    end


    if (b=='R')&&((blackFirst == whiteFirst) || (blackSecond == whiteSecond))
    fprintf('The White King at %s is threatened by black rook at %s \n',convertIntegerToCoordinates(n) ,convertIntegerToCoordinates(c));
    elseif fprintf('The White King at %s is not threatened by the black rook at %s \n', convertIntegerToCoordinates(n),convertIntegerToCoordinates(c));

    end 
    return;

    if (b=='B') && (abs(blackFirst-whiteFirst) == abs(blackSecond-whiteSecond))
    fprintf('The white king at %s is threatened by the black bishop at %s \n', convertIntegerToCoordinates(n), convertIntegerToCoordinates(c));
    elseif fprintf('The white king at %s is not threatened by the black bishop at %s \n', convertIntegerToCoordinates(n),convertIntegerToCoordinates(c));
    end 

    if  (b=='Q')&&((abs(blackFirst-whiteFirst) == abs(blackSecond-whiteSecond)) || ((blackFirst == whiteFirst) || (blackSecond == whiteSecond)))
    fprintf ('The white king at %s is threatened by black queen at %s \n', convertIntegerToCoordinates(n),convertIntegerToCoordinates(c));
    else if fprintf('The white king at %s is not threatened by black queen at %s\n', convertIntegerToCoordinates(n), convertIntegerToCoordinates(c));
    end  

    if (b=='K')&& ((abs(blackFirst-whiteFirst == 2) && abs(blackSecond-whiteSecond==1)) || (abs(blackFirst-whiteFirst == 1) && abs(blackSecond-whiteSecond==2)))
    fprintf('The white king at %s is threatened by black knight at %s \n', convertIntegerToCoordinates(n),convertIntegerToCoordinates(c));
    elseif fprintf('The white king at %s is not threatened by black knight at %s \n', convertIntegerToCoordinates(n),convertIntegerToCoordinates(c));
    end 

    end
```

3. The output is printed in the wrong way. Anyone can help me please ?
   The output im getting is

   ```
   E5E6The White King at >>
   ```

but i expect

```
    The White king at E5 is threatened by the black rook at E6 >>
```

Comment: "The output is printed in the wrong way" is not enough information. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This includes: A **runnable** code reduced to the problematic part. The output you would expect. And the output that you are actually getting.

Comment: There are several inconsistencies in your code. You specify `n`, `b`, and `c` as input but ask for them with `input` later on for instance. What values have you used as input ? What is wrong with the printed result ? I wish I could read your mind, but unfortunately I can't ;)

Comment: @Ratbert I used n as 55, b as 'R' and c as 56 . Also i added my expected output there

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `fprintf` is already called inside your `convertIntegerToCoordinates` function. Thus the function prints directly to the command window prior to the `fprintf` in the main script. Plus the fact that your function has no output variable, so the `fprintf` of the main script does not know what to put in place of the formatSpecs `'%s'`.

Here is a more compact version of your function that should fix this display problem:

```
function out = convertIntegerToCoordinates(i)

% Get column
C = char(floor(i/10)+64);

% Get raw 
R = num2str(mod(i,10));

% Output
out = [C R];
```

or, same ideas but even more compact:

```
function out = convertIntegerToCoordinates(i)

out = [char(floor(i/10)+64) num2str(mod(i,10))];
```

Best,

Comment: No, just an experienced user ;) Don't hesitate to mark the question as _solved_ if this is the case, such that the community knows you no longer need help on this matter.

Comment: I see you also shivered when you saw the `elseif`s. ;-)